# publisher.cycleVideo() in opentok web application was not working it was giving error message like below picture and content

Tags: angularjs

> opentok.min.js:31 OpenTok:Publisher:error onStreamAvailableError OT_HARDWARE_UNAVAILABLE: The selected voice or video devices are unavailable. Verify that the chosen devices are not in use by another application. (getUserMedia error: NotReadableError) +0ms
>   s @ opentok.min.js:31
>   opentok.min.js:31 OpenTok:Publisher:warn Received connectivity event: "Failure" without "Attempt" +0ms
>   s @ opentok.min.js:31
>   opentok.min.js:31 OpenTok:Global Exception Handler:error OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia +0ms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTjKU.png)

[image]

some times

```
  scope.publisher.cycleVideo()
   .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
  }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
  })
}
```

error block returns like below

> ```
> l
> code: undefined
> constraintName: undefined
> message: "The selected voice or video devices are unavailable. Verify that the chosen devices are not in use by another application. (getUserMedia error: NotReadableError)"
> name: "OT_HARDWARE_UNAVAILABLE"
> original Message: "Could not start video source"
> stack: "Error: The selected voice or video devices are unavailable. Verify that the chosen devices are not in use by another application. (getUserMedia error: NotReadableError)↵    at u  MutationObserver.p 
> __proto__: Error
> ```

Comment: I experience the same error here!